# Save actual month value Bootstrap datapicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

how do i get the actual month value in a variable in Bootstrap Datepicker?
this month "October or 10" i want to save that value.

I'm using this version, demo inside: 
http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=embedded&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=linked&language=pt&orientation=auto#sandbox

Comment: Using jQuery you could grab the value of the date field and then parse the value to get your month.

Comment: I Know the value is in the date inside of the javascript but i don't know how to get it out.

Comment: I answered it but it would be helpful to see your code.

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery something like

```
$('#buttonId').click(function(){
   var date = $('#dateFieldID').val();  // "10/11/2013"
   var month = date.substring(0,2); //Grab first two characters of the date string = 10
   alert(month); // here is your month
   // do something with your month
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks that might be helpfull i'm kind a neebie in javascript, i'm using the javascript from the link i put in the question

Comment: @user2599982 please mark this answer as accepted it answered you question.  Or give feedback if it did not.  Thanks